# NetSuite SOAP API update Opportunity line items

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, integration, netsuite

I am trying to update NetSuite Opportunity line items via SOAP API (https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2012_1_0/netsuite.wsdl).

In NS opportunity line items are setup as a group. When I try to update the line items, I am sending one item via SOAP API with the internalId that matches that group.

The only use case that is not working is when Opportunity already has line items. In that case, NS is returning the message: "USER_ERROR You cannot delete the end of group line. You must delete the group."

I also do not manage to delete those items by sending the empty items list. NS is returning the same error message as above.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There must be different method defined in your ws api to delete opportunity like you explained, You must be confused among update and delete operations. Please check once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Net Suite support, this is a bug and it is scheduled to be fixed with 2014.1 release.

Thanks to everyone involved in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use **replaceAll** parameter in your update call

http://tellsaqib.github.io/NSPHP-Doc/d4/dae/class_opportunity_item_list.html

Comment: Hi, replaceAll attribute can not help in my use case - it will just add new items, but will not delete items that are not needed any more; replaceAll default behavior is what I need.

Comment: AFAIK you can either add line items or replace line items using replaceAll parameter. In your use case you can fetch all the line item in your local variable. Manipulate the group (Add/Update/Delete Line items) and then send back the group to Netsuite along with replaceAll attribute.